# stormconf.ser doesn't exist error on worker

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have a Storm cluster with 2 nodes and 1 ZooKeeper. One of the worker dies because of the following error. Does any one have an idea on why *stormconf.ser* file is getting deleted?

I am using 0.9.2 Storm and 3.4.6 ZK version.

```
o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-01-31 01:23:06 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [WARN] There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
2015-01-31 01:23:07 b.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/home/Programs/apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating/stormtmp/supervisor/stormdist/storm-topology-1-1422602934/stormconf.ser' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1763) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at backtype.storm.config$read_supervisor_storm_conf.invoke(config.clj:212) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data.invoke(worker.clj:180) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5940$exec_fn__1396__auto____5941.invoke(worker.clj:356) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5940$mk_worker__5996.doInvoke(worker.clj:347) [storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:454) [storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
2015-01-31 01:23:07 b.s.util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was known issue in the old releases of Storm. Usually what you need to do is to clear the directories that Storm is using. Check for the name of those files in Storm's configuration file `conf/storm.yaml`.

Comment: i got this reference from user group https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-130

Answer (score 2):

Just to make it clear: this issue appears to be fixed in Storm 0.9.4.

Details in the issue linked by @tousif: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-130

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the version of hdp to 2.5 or less
Use storm verion 1.0.1
It solved the issue...
clearing the directory is useless idea.