# storm topology unable to find stormconf.ser file

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am running storm topology on my cluster and I could find that the topology is submitted successfully. But it is not reading messages from Kafka. And when I checked the Topology logs in storm I could find that their is the issue with stormconf.ser file.
it is not able to find this file in the path like - /archive/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/FieldsGrouping_Topology-2-1441255014/stormconf.ser

Here is the full Stack Trace ---

```
2015-09-03 00:39:06 b.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/archive/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/FieldsGrouping_Topology-2-1441255014/stormconf.ser' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1763) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at backtype.storm.config$read_supervisor_storm_conf.invoke(config.clj:214) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__6019$exec_fn__1142__auto____6020.invoke(worker.clj:382) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
```

Please help me on this.....
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if the folder/file exists? Is your storm.yaml configuration the same for the nimbus and supervisor hosts with regard to "storm.local.dir" parameter?

Comment: yes I had checked the storm.yaml file...its same and proper....also initially my other storm topology  is working but now its not working...and also I had checked the directory for the storm topology doesn't exist....

Comment: Maybe you want to clear (ie, rm -rf *) your local.storm.dir on all nodes (need to stop the whole cluster before it and re-start it afterwards). If this does not help, I have no further ideas...

Comment: Matthias-after removing all contents from this folder, it starts working.can you please help what this folder actually contains, as this problem is occurring many time in clustered environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stormconf.ser doesn't exist error on worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272355/stormconf-ser-doesnt-exist-error-on-worker)